# TypeError: _this.callback is not a function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Unable to create POST request using NodeJS. Getting error "TypeError: _this.callback is not a function".

```
const vertica = require('vertica');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var db = require('./db-connection')

app.use(bodyparser.json());

//Listening port
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Express Server is running at port no. : 3000 '));

//Convert into query results into JSON
function mapToJSON(dbResult) {
const fieldNames = dbResult.fields.map(field => field.name) // List of all field names

return dbResult.rows.map(row => {
    return row.reduce((obj, item, index) => {
        const header = fieldNames[index]
        obj[header] = item
        return obj
    }, {})
})
}


//Get function 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
db.query('select SUM(TOTAL_THROUGHPUT_RECEIVED)*(8/1024)/NULLIFZERO(SUM(COUNTER_THROUGHPUT_DL)) 
AVG_THROUGHPUT_DL from omniq.AGG_QICARE_ANALYZE_15_MIN WHERE PROCEDURE_TYPE = 816 and IMSI 
=515021161429077 ', (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (!err)
        res.send(mapToJSON(rows));
    else
        console.log(err)
})
});

app.post('/avgthrptDL', (req, res) => {
var IMSI = req.body.IMSI;
var PROCEDURE_TYPE = req.body.PROCEDURE_TYPE;

console.log("IMSI " + IMSI + " PT " + PROCEDURE_TYPE)

db.query('select SUM(TOTAL_THROUGHPUT_RECEIVED)*(8/1024)/NULLIFZERO(SUM(COUNTER_THROUGHPUT_DL)) 
AVG_THROUGHPUT_DL from omniq.AGG_QICARE_ANALYZE_15_MIN WHERE PROCEDURE_TYPE = ? and IMSI = ?', 
[IMSI, PROCEDURE_TYPE], function (err, results) {
     if (err) 
   res.status(500).json({error: err});
else
res.status(200).json(results);
});
});
```

When I run the above code. I got this error "TypeError: _this.callback is not a function". How can I overcome this? I want to send PROCEDURE_TYPE and IMSI detail by JSON. Could not get any response.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4bq2.png)

Comment: Replace `return callback(results);` with `res.send(results)`.

Comment: no callback function is declared, simply use res.json(result)

Comment: Since you have a callstack, look at it and trace back how it is is triggered from your own code. This should reveal what you are doing incorrectly.

Comment: @Anupam Mishra Can you post your `./db-connection`??

Comment: @Subburaj:- when I use this part of code. Then I got the correct response. 
 app.post('/avgthrptDL',(req,res)=>{
 var IMSI = req.body.IMSI;
 var PT = req.body.PROCEDURE_TYPE;
 console.log("IMSI"+ IMSI + " PT"+ PT);
 db.query('select SUM(TOTAL_THROUGHPUT_RECEIVED)*(8/1024)/NULLIFZERO(SUM(COUNTER_THROUGHPUT_DL)) AVG_THROUGHPUT_DL from omniq.AGG_QICARE_ANALYZE_15_MIN WHERE PROCEDURE_TYPE = 816 and IMSI =515021161429077' , (err,results)=>{
  if(!err)
   res.send(results);
  else
   console.log(err)
 })
 });

Comment: @Felix Kling:- I am newbie in NodeJs. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This error occured because your `callback` function is never declared.

I think instead returning your value, you should send as a JSON response like this :

```
res.status(200).json(results);
```

And you also need a 'else', because in case of any error, you will send twice a response.

```
db.query('<your SQL query>', function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({error: err});
    }
    else {
        res.status(200).json(results);
        // return callback(results); // Error occured here
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. but this is also not working. I got the same error.